# PySpark applyinpands/grouped_map pandas_udf too many arguments

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use the [pyspark `applyInPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html) in my python code. Problem is, the function that I want to pass to it exists in the same class, and so it is defined as `def func(self, key, df)`. This becomes an issue because `applyInPandas` will error out saying I'm passing too many arguments to the underlying func (at most it allows a `key` and `df` params, so the `self` is causing the issue). Is there any way around this?

The underlying goal is to process a pandas function on dataframe groups in parallel.

Comment: Did you pass in `self.func`? This should automatically fill in the `self` parameter.

Comment: I did, the problem lies in that applyInPandas is built in a way that requires the underlying function (that is passed to it) to only have 2 parameters

Comment: Do you really need the self? Can you make it staticmethod?

Comment: That is my current workaround, but it is pretty ugly and defeats the purpose of trying to organize my code within classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OP mentioned, one way is to just use `@staticmethod`, which may not be desirable in some cases.

The [pyspark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/functions.py)  for creating pandas_udf uses `inspect.getfullargspec().args` (line 386, 436), this includes `self` even if the class method is called from the instance. I would think this is a bug on their part (maybe worthwhile to raise a ticket).

To overcome this, the easiest way is to use `functools.partial` which can help change the argspec, i.e. remove the `self` argument and restore the number of args to 2.

This is based on the idea that calling an instance method is the same as calling the method directly from the class and supply the instance as the first argument (because of the descriptor magic):

```
A.func(A(), *args, **kwargs) == A().func(*args, **kwargs)
```

In a concrete example,

```
import functools
import inspect


class A:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def sum(self, a: int, b: int):
        return (a + b) * self.y

    def x(self):
        # calling the method using the class and then supply the self argument
        f = functools.partial(A.sum, self)  
        print(f(1, 2))
        print(inspect.getfullargspec(f).args)
        
A(2).x()
```

This will print

```
6           # can still use 'self.y'
['a', 'b']  # 2 arguments (without 'self')
```

Then, in OP's case, one can simply do the same for `key, df` parameters:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def func(self, key, df):
        ...

    def x(self):
        f = functools.partial(A.func, self)
        self.df.groupby(...).applyInPandas(f)
```

Comment: this is really cool... but scares me :)